# Dificuldade para capturar elemento. WebDriver com C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

estou com dificuldades para capturar informação de um span.

Já tentei diversas formas (ID, Xpath, Csselector) mas não tem jeito.

Se alguém puder dar uma luz agradeço.
Essa é a imagem do código e a informação que preciso capturar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Precisei utilizar esse código pra retornar o valor da tela.
isso funciona usando o ChromiumWebBrowser, mas o principio é o mesmo, por no final das contas é mandar um JS.

```
browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"function retornaSituacao() {
               var texto = document.getElementById('ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_VersaoLabel').[0].innerText;
               return texto;
}
retornaSituacao();");
```